# Removing URLConnection object from ArrayList<URLConnection>

Tags: java, arraylist, urlconnection

In my program I need to track list of opened connections to some HTTP server - in order to disconnect them at once if needed.

I faced the following problem. If I connect to HTTP server everything works perfect, but if to HTTPS, then connections are not removed from the list. It leads to memory leak.

Example:

```
package test;

import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ArrayList<URLConnection> al = new ArrayList<URLConnection>();

            URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com");

            URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
            al.add(conn);
            System.out.println("Result of removing = " + al.remove(conn));

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
}
```

If URL points to "http://www.example.com" then "Result of removing = true".

But if URL points to "https://www.example.com" then "Result of removing = false".

I don't understand such a behavior. I have some assumptions, but not not sure...

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short (at least, with HotSpot JVM 23.7-b01) we have that `conn.equals(conn)==false` when the URL scheme is HTTPS.

The operation `remove(Object o)` is [defined](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html) as removing an element *e* such that `(o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))` (i.e. remove is defined in terms of *equals*). One could expect that remove(conn) succeed, since the element has just been inserted, but since `conn.equals(conn)` is `false`, the collection implementation understand that the element is not contained.

This is a strange case where *equals* is not reflexive. From [the openjdk implementation](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/build-infra/jdk7/jdk/file/0f8da27a3ea3/src/share/classes/sun/net/www/protocol/https/HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java) the reason is clear: `HttpsURLConnectionImpl` delegates the implementation of *equals* to an internal object, which is **not equal** to the wrapper.

```
public class HttpsURLConnectionImpl {
   protected DelegateHttpsURLConnection delegate;
   public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return delegate.equals(obj);
   }
}
```

Comment: So, it is really the case of strange behaviour of _equals_... I sent away such explanation because it is really mad... Thanks! BTW, don't you know any other examples of classes with such _equals_ behavior?

Comment: No, indeed I didn't know this one either. The only case of a defective implementation of *equals* that I can recall now is that of java.net.URL (in this case the flaw is about consistency: the equality relation depends on DNS resolution, thus two URL instances might or might not be equal depending on the resolved IP address, but that is a different story).